# HTTPS access to external URL

Tags: html, https, cross-domain

I am trying to use an anchor tag, where on click on the anchor it will open the external url (https protocol) in the separate tab. This works fine when my site is opened in HTTP but it does not work when I am opening my site in HTTPS.

My anchor tag :

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://externalDomain/someLink">
   <img src="image.png">
</a>
```

When my site is in HTTP then it opens the above url which is in https. But when my site is in https then it is not able to open the above url in the new tab.
Actually in this case it is trying to open the following URL :
https://mySite/someLink

Comment: In what browser is this? What context is your site in, is it in an intranet?

Comment: This is to be expected, you most likely violate the "same origin policy". There are security considerations why browsers block such attempts. You want to read about how that policy work and how to send the correct http headers to solve your problem.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply.
I understand the same origin policy. But in this case when my site is opened in HTTP then on clicking the anchor tag it is successfully opening the HTTPS external url in the new tab. But the issue is occurring only when my site is also opened in the HTTPS then it is not able to open the external https url in the new tab.
One thing which i have observed is, when my site is opened in HTTP then the cookies are not being sent to the external site but when my site is opened in the HTTPS then cookies are also being sent in the request.